# How to prevent call function call on instance of subclass that is being destroyed

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just had to put in a fix for a difficult-to-find error, but I am not happy about the fix. Our application is C++ running in Windows, and the error was a pure virtual call crash. Here is some background:

```
class Observable
{
public:
    Observable();
    virtual ~Observable();
    void Attach(Observer&); // Seize lock, then add Observer to the list
    void Detach(Observer&); // Seize lock, then remove Observer from the list
    void Notify(); // Seize lock, then iterate list and call Update() on each Observer

protected:
    // List of attached observers
};

class Subject : public Observable
{
    // Just important to know there is a subclass of Observable
}

class Observer
{
public:
    Observer();
    virtual ~Observer(); // Detaches itself from the Observable
    void Update() = 0;
};

class Thing : public Observer
{
public:
    void Update(); // What it does is immaterial to this question
};
```

Because this is a multi-threaded environment, there are locks in place for Attach(), Detach(), and Notify(). Notify() seizes the lock and then iterates the list of observers and calls Update() on each one.

(I hope this is enough of a background without having to post the complete body of code.)

The problem arose when an observer was being destroyed. On destruction, the Observer detaches itself from the Observable. At the same time, in another thread, Notify() is being called on the Subject. My original thought was that we were protected because of the locks in Detach() (called on destruction of the Observer), and Notify(). However, C++ destroys the subclass first, then the base class. This meant that, before the lock in Detach() was obtained which would have prevented the Notify() function from continuing, the implementation of the pure virtual Update() function was destroyed. The Notify() function continued (because it had already obtained the lock) and attempted to call Update(). The result is a crash.

Now, here is my solution, which works, but gives me a queasy feeling. I changed the Update() function from being pure virtual to just being virtual and provided a body that did nothing. The reason this bothers me is that Update() is still being called, but on a partially destructed object. In other words, I am getting away with something, but I am not wild about the implementation.

Other options discussed:

1) Move the locking into the subclasses. Not desirable because it forces the developer of each subclass to duplicate the logic. And if he omits the locking, bad things can happen.

2) Force the destruction of the observer to occur via a Destroy() function. Honestly, I wasn't sure how to implement this for stack-based objects.

3) Have the subclass call a "PreDestroy()" function in its destructor to notify the base class that destruction is imminent. I wouldn't know how to force this, and forgetting it could lead to hard-to-find runtime errors.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to a better way to protect against these types of crashes? I have this unpleasant feeling that I am missing the elephant in the room.

JAB

Comment: TL;DR. Can you provide more minimal example with code?

Comment: Is it undesirable to wrap every `Observable` in a shared pointer, to ensure destruction occurs at a 'safe' time? Or to turn the `Observable` into a reference counted object

Comment: With shared pointers the problem would be (if you suggest to keep the observers in the observable as shared pointers) that the observers would actually not be destroyed when the observer (shared ptr) goes out of scope (there will be at least one reference kept in the list in Observable). That would basically force to always use Detach explicitly. And of course not possible to have stack based observers then.

Comment: Boost [Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/signals2.html) may be worth a look.

Comment: @axalis: the Observable could hold Observer via weak pointer. I'd happyly go without stack bases Observers.

Comment: @stefan True, but then I'm not entirely sure that it would work either. The observable might already dereference the weak pointer and be about to call Update, but in the meantime the shared ptr outside might go out of scope (in the other thread) and start destroying the observer before the first thread manages to actually call Update. But perhaps that could be solved by a temporary sharedptr acquired by the Observable just for the call of Update (which will increase the reference count and prevent the observer from being destroyed during the Update call).

Comment: @axalis: the shared pointer is thread safe. if the Observable manages to get a shared pointer from the weak pointer it is valid. So the owner of the Observer simply drops the shared pointer. Either the Observable already managed to ge a pointer, or the control block survives for the weak pointers to deny any furter conversions to shared pointer and the Observer object dies.

Answer (score 1):

About your solutions:

1. Not good, because of the reasons you give.
2. Ok. Additionally, define `~Observer()` as `protected` (as any other destructor of derived classes) to avoid calling `delete` directly and write a member `void Destroy()`. The problem is that it will not work for automatic (local) variables. Actually, with a protected destructor you will not be able to declare local variables.
3. You probably mean calling `PreDestroy()` from the destructor of each subclass destructor. The problem will be not to forget it (you can assert that it has been called from `~Observer()`) and if you have several levels of inheritance.

About your original solution:

4. Making `Update()` a callable virtual function seems to work, but it is technically wrong. While one thread is calling the virtual `Update()`, using the vtable pointer, another thread is calling `~Thing()` and updating the vtable pointer to that of `Observer()`. The first thread holds the lock, but the second one does not, so you have a race.

My advice would be use option 2 unless you are very fond of automatic instances of subclasses of `Observer`.

---

If you are willing, you could try with templates:

```
template<typename O>
class ObserverPtr : Observer
{
 public:
    ObserverPtr(O *obj)
     :m_obj(obj)
    {}
    void Update()
    {
        m_obj->Update();
    }
    ~ObserverPtr()
    {
        PreDestroy();
        delete m_obj;
    }
 private:
    O *m_obj;
};
```

And then `Thing` will not derive from `Observer`.

You can also create alternative variants of this template:

- to hold a reference to the real observer instead of a pointer (`O &m_obj;`). No use of `delete`.
- to define the real observer as an actual member (`O m_obj;`). No dynamic allocations.
- to hold a smart pointer to the real observer.

Comment: Yes, even with defined (not pure) base Update function there still might be a problem. Because it might happen, that the inherited Thing::Update will be called, and it might try to use some attributes of the Thing. But in the meantime another thread might already proceed with the destruction of Thing, and the Thing::Update method might end up using attributes which were already destroyed (and that would be even more difficult to debug than the pure virtual function call).

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a template. I need to see if I can make this work in our environment.

Comment: @axalis -- I see your point. We have had some hard-to-reproduce crashes. What you describe might be the source of some of those.

Comment: I finally had a chance to look at this again. I must be missing something because I think your solution above is just kicking the can down the road, so to speak. What is the relationship between ObserverPtr and Thing? I assumed Thing would be a subclass of ObserverPtr, but that would make it a subclass of Observer. I am not sure I see it.

Comment: @JAB: The idea of the template is that `Thing` derives from nothing. You write `Thing *t = new Thing;` and it is not observing anything. Then you do `ObserverPtr<Thing> obs(t);` and `t` will be in the list while the `obs` object is alive. You could also make the template derive from the type itself: `template <typename O> class ObserverObj : Observer, O { ... };`, instead of including a member of type `O m_obj` or `O *m_obj`.

Comment: @rodrigo: I think I have to make the template derive from type. If I don't, the type instance could be destroyed and the template object would have a pointer to garbage.

Comment: @JAB: If you derive your `Thing` from the template, then the situation is no different than your original code. My idea is that your instance never outlives the template object. You could have a `std::weak_ptr<T>` as member, for example, to avoid that restriction. My other idea of the `ObserverObj` that derives both from `Observer` and `O` is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is an illustration of a more general consequence of multi-threaded design:   no object that is affected by multiple threads can provide a guarantee of no concurrent access to itself at any point in time.    This consequence is the elephant in the room that is giving you the unpleasant feeling you describe at the end of your question.

In short, your problem is that `Attach()`, `Detach()`, and `Notify()` are responsible for both grabbing the appropriate lock and doing their thing.   They need to be able to assume the lock is grabbed before they are called.

Unfortunately, the solution requires a more complicated design.   It is necessary for some single source that is independent of your objects (or classes) to mediate the construction, updating (including attaching and detaching), and destruction of all your objects.  And it is necessary to prevent any of those processes from occurring independently of the mediator.

It is a design choice whether you prevent those processes by technical means (e.g. access control, etc) or simply state policies that all your types must comply with.    That choice depends on whether you can rely on your developers (including yourself) to follow policy guidelines.

Comment: `[...] no object that is affected by multiple threads can provide a guarantee of no concurrent access to itself at any point in time.` +1

Comment: I had considered the idea of using a mediator. As you state, there are design challenges to that approach as well. Also, I was hoping for a solution that didn't rely on the developer remembering to adhere to a policy. Mainly because I would be most likely to forget!

Comment: Although you didn't say it in your question, I suspected you might have considered a mediator.  I suggest you look at it more closely.  In the end, you need to remove responsibility from your objects related to thread synchronisation.   There will be issues with protecting the mediator (it can't protect *itself*) but those can be managed a bit more easily if the number of mediators is limited (e.g. a singleton).

Answer (score 0):

I think that unless you mandate to call Detach from the derived class destructor, it will not have an easy solution.

One solution which comes into my mind might be to utilize an extra "wrapper" which will take care of de-registration (and might actually do the registration as well).

Something like this (for example):

```
class ObserverAgent;

// the wrapper class - not virtual
class Observer
{
public:
    Observer(Observable &subject, ObserverAgent &agent)
        : _subject(subject), _agent(agent)
    {
        _subject.Attach(*this);
    }
    ~Observer()
    {
        _subject.Detach(*this);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        _agent.Update();
    }
private:
    Observable &_subject;
    ObserverAgent &_agent;
};

// the actual observer polymorphic object
class ObserverAgent
{
public:
    ObserverAgent();
    virtual ~ObserverAgent();
protected:
    // only callable by the Observer wrapper
    friend class Observer;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
};

class Thing : public ObserverAgent
{
public:
    virtual void Update();
};
```

The use is then indeed more convoluted:

```
Subject s;
{ // some scope
    Thing t;
    Observer o(s, t);
    // do stuff
} // here first Observer is detached and destroyed, then Thing (already unregistered)
```

Note that you cannot Attach/Detach Thing (ObserverAgent) directly, only through Observer (because Observable takes the Observer, not the ObserverAgent).

Perhaps it could be possible to wrap it in a single class for simpler use (Agent being an inner class of the Observer), however then there might be problems with the lifetime of the agents (as the destruction of the Observer would have to be virtual again).

Answer (score 0):

Why not expose the lock as `protected` in `Observable`? `Observable::~Observable` acquires the lock if it's not acquired already by this thread, then goes on with the cleanup. Meanwhile EVERY subclass of Observable acquires the lock in its dtor without further releasing it (which is only done in ~Observable itself).

Frankly, in this design the simplest and the most consistent solution seems to manually Detach() each Observer at the very start of the most derived class' destructor. I don't see how this can be automated, and since something has to be done at the dawn of destruction, why not detachment.

...Well, if we don't need to go deeper:

```
template<class Substance> struct Observer {
    Observer(Observable &o): o(o) { o.attach(s); }
    ~Observer() { o.detach(s); }
    Substance &subst() const { return s; }
private:
    Observable &o;
    Substance s;
};
struct ThingSubst { void update(); long stats(); };
typedef Observer<ThingSubst> Thing;

Observable o;
Thing thing(o);
std::cout << thing.subst().stats() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I thought about this, but the problem is that is it incumbent on the developer of the subclass to remember to add the lock to the destructor of  the subclass. I was hoping for a solution that would handle this issue automatically in the base class.

Comment: The problem is, lock acquisition in this design should last for the whole period of time while the destruction goes, from the most derived up to the base class.